# Excel Not Recognising Variables in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am writing an SQL statement into a regular Excel sheet (not VBA), which can be copied and pasted from a cell into SQL Server Management Studio.

In order for it to work, however, I need to declare variables (for example @userid). Usually, Excel has no problem with me using variables, but when I put them into an IF statement, it tells me that it's an 'invalid function'.

For instance, one part of my SQL query looks like this:

```
="VALUES("&IF(Keys!B5<>"", Keys!B5, "@spid")&", @sid, GETDATE())"
```

For now I've had to add quotes around the variables. Unfortunately this means that, when pasting into SQL Server Management Studio, you then have to remove the quotes around the variables again in order for them to be recognised as variables and not strings. This is inconvenient, as my spreadsheet is supposed to be designed to make adding records quicker and easier.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: Sample output from your formula: `VALUES(55, @sid, GETDATE())`, so it's unclear what _quotes_ need to be removed, when you paste it to SMS.

Comment: For me it always appears as '@spid' after pasting the code into SMS, if I am forced to surround it with " " quotes.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it in SMS2012, the sql code is pasted in exactly the same form as it appears in Excel formula result.

Comment: My issue is, SMS likes it when I type it without quotes, but Excel doesn't. It will tell me "That function isn't valid", and will keep telling me that until I've fixed it. I can't press enter to get a result for the query in Excel, unless I surround "@spid" with quotes. So I'm forced to paste that into SMS, which turns "@spid" into '@spid', so it thinks it's a string.

Comment: I still don't understand, there is `"@spid"` in your formula, but there is `@spid` or `@sid` without double quotes in formula result (as I pasted in the first comment), so where do those extra quotes come from? can you add screenshot of your formulas result?

Comment: I see what you mean. I just tried it again and it doesn't seem to be doing it anymore. Strange. There must have been another part of my formula that was incorrect. It would still come out as `"@spid"` in the formula result instead of `@spid` like it should, and so it would appear like that when I pasted into SMS. The only reason I had to wrap it in quotes in the first place is so that Excel would recognise it as a variable. Otherwise it would spit errors at me and I wouldn't be able to type anything into the cell. It shouldn't have included the quote marks in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of possible work-arounds you might be able to put to use.

1. Use `'@spid` in Key!B5. The single tick used as the [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) will not be added to the concatenated string.
2. Use `spid` in Key!B5 and put the **@** in the formula string parts. 
          `="VALUES(@"&IF(Keys!B5<>"", Keys!B5, "spid")&", @sid, GETDATE())"`
3. Same as 2. but format Key!B5 as with a custom number format mask of `\@@` The `\` is an escape character to make the first @ literal. This will show the value as `@spid` when the cell actually contains `spid`.

Comment: I don't think I explained my formula clear enough. If cell B5 in the Keys sheet is not blank (so it contains a number), use that value. If the cell is blank, use the value in the '@spid' variable instead. The value of the '@spid' variable is generated in another part of my full SQL query. Would it be more helpful to post the whole query?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was another named variable (although I confused matter further by using the same name). I'll give this some more thought.